# Add date in taken picture DELPHI FIREMONKEY

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey

For a photo app that I am making, the date on which the photo was taken must be in the photo. and then saved in the folder. Now I don't know what components to use to do this. or how to do this at all.

Like this :[image]

Thanks in advance for any help !!

Comment: Does it have to be the font that you used in the example picture?

Comment: Just the date in an corner

Comment: Load the image into a bitmap, draw the date on bitmap, write back the bitmap to the image. Please note that the date should also be in the metadata of the image.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read jpeg exif data. There are several free Delphi codes to do that. Two examples are
https://github.com/cutec-chris/dexif/blob/master/dEXIF.pas
https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/ccr-exif/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any component to do so, just use the `TCanvas` of the `TBitmap` as:

```
Var
  R: TRectF;
  Img: TBitmap;
begin
  Img:= TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Img.LoadFromFile('C:\MyPic.jpg');
    R.Create(Img.Width - 100, Img.Height - 100, Img.Width, Img.Height);
    Img.Canvas.BeginScene();
    Img.Canvas.Fill.Kind:= TBrushKind.Solid;
    Img.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness:= 12;
    Img.Canvas.Stroke.Color:= TAlphaColors.White;
    Img.Canvas.FillText(
    R, DateToStr(Now), False, 100, [TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft], TTextAlign.Center);
    Img.Canvas.EndScene;
    Img.SaveToFile('D:\Result.jpg');
  finally
    Img.Free;
  end;
```

If you want to set the creation date to the picture, you can use `TFile.SetCreationTime()`.

Comment: If an exception occurs when the file is saved, you leak the bitmap object. Use the standard idioms unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: That demonstrates writing the current date, but not getting the date the photo was taken from the exif data.